# Is every regular language Turing-decidable, and how can we prove this?

Tags: terminology, computability, regular-languages, decision-problem

I know every regular language is Turing-acceptable, but does that imply it is Turing-decidable?

Comment: How do you show that every regular language is recognizable? Can you use the same technique to show that it's decidable?

Comment: @Raphael- I don't think it's fair to close this question.  Many textbooks don't directly address this.  I think this question is clearly-written and well-phrased, and the fact that it is not very complicated doesn't seem like a reason to close it.

Comment: @templatetypedef, echadromani: it's not about the level, it's about the SE-badness of the question. The raw information is readily available -- to the point that we have to assume the asker either has the information at hand or the question is homework -- but the asker seems to have some problems with basic definitions. This is not clear, however, from the form of the question. Please see [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a discussion on the matter; if you want to discuss this further, please open a question on [meta].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every regular language is Turing-decidable and therefore Turing acceptable / recognisable (but note that Turing acceptable does not imply Turing decidable).

Suppose you are given a DFA D such that L = L(D). One can construct a Turing Machine T that simulates D. T's states will be similar to D's. On reaching the end of the input, if T is in a state that corresponds to a final state of D, T halts and accepts; otherwise it halts and rejects.